# Sqldelight 1.4 how insert filled data generated object without primarykey (id)

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

I have problem with saving data to sqldelight 1.4 in Android app.

I created table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);
```

In repo class I have insert function with myTable object as an argument

```
fun insert(item: myTable) {
     myTableQueries.insert( 
        name = item.name
     )
}
```

And in some action i try to create new object Table with name but without id, as id is auto incremented.
I had not found any info how to do that.
Which is the best solution?

1. Create a new class (myTablexpress) with the same parameters as the data class (myTable), use this object in the argument of the insert function in the repo class, and use these parameters?
2. Not create a new myTable instance in action class, but use insert function and put string value as parameter?

```
myTableViewModel.insert(name)
```

3. Create new class myTable without id

```
@Parcelize
class myTable(val name: String) : Parcelable
```

and in viewmodel use params?

4. none of them

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This topic is already discusssed in sqldelight issue here: https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/1284

You can define your sqlite `insert` statement in your .sq file using `?` parameters for all the variables, as the doc of sqldelight states: https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/android_sqlite/

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE hockeyPlayer (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  player_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  full_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

insert:
INSERT INTO hockeyPlayer
VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

And from your Kotlin code you can pass `null` for its id, which makes auto-incrementation work:

```kotlin
query.insert(
  id = null,
  player_number = 100,
  full_name = "name"
)
```

Comment: If I add AUTOINCREMENT to the .sqm file I get error `')', ',', <column constraint real>, ASC, DESC or ON expected, got 'AUTOINCREMENT'`

Comment: If I have the ` id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` there is error  when inserting null: `Null can not be a value of a non-null type Int`. Maybe its because I'm using postgres.